# How would one know if the SharingLink is 'Anyone', 'New and existing guests', 'Existing guests', or 'Only people in your organization'?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

I am trying to understand the difference in SharingLinks so I can perform some cleanup actions on SharingLinks in our tenant using PowerShell.

How would one know if the SharingLink is 'Anyone', 'New and existing guests', 'Existing guests', or 'Only people in your organization'?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward way is using the Sharing Report in SharePoint Online. You can create a CSV file of every unique file, user, permission and link on a given SharePoint site or OneDrive. This can help you understand how sharing is being used and if any files or folders are being shared with guests. You must be a site admin to run the report.

To run the report (SharePoint)

1. Open the site where you want to run the report
2. On the Settings menu, click **Site usage**.
3. In the **Shared with external users** section, click **Run report**.
4. Choose a location to save the report, and then click **Run report**.

More Information here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharing-reports